# SolrCloud ConfigApi and configoverlay difference

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to change configuration through ConfigApi. When I use update in single node environment everything works as expected. 
With multiple nodes ConfigApi update-searchcomponent returns:

```
3 out of 4 the property overlay to be of version 13 within 30 seconds!
```

configoverlay.json under Cloud section contains updated values but ConfigApi and configoverlay.json under Files section contains wrong values.

I am using SolrCloud 7.1 with 3 shards.

Comment: Did you try waiting those 30 seconds? As in, is this a stable-state issue?

Comment: Request waits for 30 seconds. There might be another problem with my solr configuration because there is actually 3 shards not 4. What i dont understand is, why there would be a difference between ConfigApi, configoverlay.json under Files and under Cloud.